# unresolved token - c++

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to solve a lesson in my study. I am going to have an abstract class, CFigure, on top and different figures below, currently I have made a circle class. I am going to call this from a C# program.

But when I try to build my code I get the following error messages:

- unresolved token (06000001) arealBeregnerCPP.CFigure::area
- unresolved token (06000002) arealBeregnerCPP.CFigure::circumference
- 2 unresolved externals

I hope anyone can give me a hint in what I do wrong... Thanks!

This is my program:

```
// arealBeregnerCPP.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace arealBeregnerCPP {

    public ref class CFigure
    {
    public:
        virtual double area();
        virtual double circumference();
    };

    public ref class CCircle : public CFigure
    {
    private:
        double m_radius;

    public:
        CCircle(double radius) 
        {
            m_radius = radius;
        }

        virtual double area() override
        {
            return 0; //not implementet
        }

        virtual double circumference() override
        {
            return 0; //not implementet
        }       
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is c++-cli related question.

Comment: @Dialecticus: it's for sure not a C++ question, since it's not C++ code. However, it is C++/CLI code. As far as I can determine.

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: we can separate the code from the question. The code is C++/CLI, but the question itself requires only standard C++ and is not CLI related.

Comment: @Dialecticus: you have to answer the question to see that the most likely answers are the same in both languages. Should the tag then be a third language for which the most likely answers are also the same? Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `CFigure::area()` and `CFigure::circumference()` are abstract functions then put `= 0` in declaration:

```
    virtual double area() = 0;
    virtual double circumference() = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you haven't defined `area` and `circumference`.

Since you fail to present complete code there are some other possibilities, such as failing to link with the relevant files.

By the way, please don't tag c++/cli questions as c++. Microsoft's c++/cli is not c++. It's a language similar to c++, but it's not c++.

Cheers & hth.,